# It is impossible to find a multi-surface whose surroundings are equal to its area and its size

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry

I had a guess from three years ago that I couldn't prove

It is impossible to find a polyhedron whose perimeter (represented by the sum of the lengths of its edges) is equal to its area (represented by the sum of the areas of its faces) and numerically equal to its volume

It is easy to find a similar shape with any shape such that two of these are equal to each other, but the question is whether all three are equal to each other.

All I have been able to prove is that this shape cannot be a Rectangular cuboid, I also proved that it is impossible for it to be a Platonic solid but I do not know if this would hold in the general case.

Here is a proof of the condition of the Rectangular cuboid by arabic language

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect there are such polyhedra. We could start with a simple one with volume much bigger than surface area and "perimeter"; then modify it by adding a thin cuboid with essentially zero volume but additional area and perimeter; then modify that with a doubly thin cuboid that essentially only increases the perimeter. With so many parameters, I suspect there are lots of examples where they are all equal.

Comment: Give me one example, I've proven it's impossible to be a rectangular cuboid.

Comment: The circumference function is a linear function and the space function is a quadratic function and the size function is a cubist function, and each pair of these functions share two points, one of which is zero. Quadratic function and cubic function in the same two points, one of which is zero, so if we find a case like this for a specific shape, the single size of this shape will be achieved.